# I want to put an additional sku in the product page but getting an error null

Tags: magento2

I want to put an additional sku in the product page.

I have this code:

```
<?php
$product = $block->getCurrentProduct();
$sku = $product->getData('sku');
if (trim($sku) !== "") : ?>
<div class="product-info-sku">
    <?php echo $sku; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but I got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in /var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/custom/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute/additional_sku.phtml:3 S
```

product xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.additional.sku" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute/additional_sku.phtml" before="product.info.price"/>
            </referenceContainer>
</referenceContainer>
```

What did I do wrong? I'm new to Magento

Comment: $product = $block->getData('product');
this $product doesnt have anything, means its an empty object,  thats wht its saying call to a member function on null

Comment: I used the same code with my custom attribute "brand" and it's working fine

Comment: print_r($product) see, is there sku in it or not?

Comment: Try `$block->getProduct()`

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
<?php
$product = $block->getData('product');
$sku = $product->getSku();
if (trim($sku) !== "") : ?>
<div class="product-info-sku">
    <?php echo $sku; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?
```

Comment: it's still showing me the same error